# Delphi Calling an API Function (SOAP)

Tags: delphi, api, soap

I have retrieved an API from a company that we are looking to integrate with using their provided WSDL.  Here is the snippet of code in the API in which I am having an issue:

```
  AppointmentRequest = class(TRemotable)
  private
    FStartDate: TXSDateTime;
    FEndDate: TXSDateTime;
    FProperty_: Property_;
    FServiceIDs: ArrayOfInt;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  published
    property StartDate: TXSDateTime read FStartDate write FStartDate;
    property EndDate: TXSDateTime read FEndDate write FEndDate;
    property Property_: Property_ read FProperty_ write FProperty_;
    property ServiceIDs: ArrayOfInt read FServiceIDs write FServiceIDs;
  end;
```

In my code I am attempting to set the Start & End Date property as follows:

```
  aApptReq  := c_xxx_API.AppointmentRequest.Create();
  aApptReq.StartDate.AsDateTime := Date();
  aApptReq.EndDate.AsDateTime := Date() + 7;
```

I believe this worked at one point but now throws an error of Access Violation at Address...  When I hover over aApptReq.StartDate (or EndDate) it shows as 'nil'.

I tried to do aApptReq.StartDate.Create() but that didn't help.

What am I missing in using this API object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create the TXSDateTime element yourself.

```
aApptReq  := c_xxx_API.AppointmentRequest.Create();   
aApptReq.StartDate := TXSDateTime.Create;
aApptReq.StartDate.AsDateTime := Date;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your quick response.  That was exactly what I needed to do.